# List categories and show subcategories when select category with json

Tags: javascript, json

I made a page like this with json. I added my test example the link at the bottom of the article. I listed the categories in this way with json. But there is something else I want. After selecting the category, I want to show the subcategories of the selected category on the screen, on the same page, maybe in the same area. How can I do this?

these are the codes I added as an example. You can see the site I prepared at the bottom of the article.

So actually when the category is selected, I want to show subcategory on the screen.

HTML

```
<ul id="category" class="grid">
</ul>
```

JAVASCRİPT

```
$(function() {

    var people = [];
    $.getJSON("category.json", function (data) {
        $.each(data.cat_en, function(i, f) {
        var tblRow = '<li class="grid_item">' + '<a href="' + f.cat_url +'">'+ '<div>'+'<div>'+'</img>'+'</div>'+ '<div>'+ f.cat_name + '<span>'+ f.cat_product_count +'</span>' + '</div>'+ '</div>'+'</a>'+'</li>' 
        
        $(tblRow).appendTo("#category")
        })
    })
})
```

JSON

```
{
    "cat_en" : 
    [
        {
          "cat_name": "Aluminum Components",
          "cat_url": "#",
          "cat_product_count": 29
        },
        {
          "cat_name": "Gas Springs",
          "cat_url": "#",
          "cat_product_count": 75
        },
        {
          "cat_name": "Lighting Parts",
          "cat_url": "#",
          "cat_product_count": 271
        },
        {
          "cat_name": "Rear View Mirrors And Components",
          "cat_url": "#",
          "cat_product_count": 71
        },
        {
          "cat_name": "Freezer And Components",
          "cat_url": "#",
          "cat_product_count": 22
        },
        {
          "cat_name": "Upholstery fabrics",
          "cat_url": "#",
          "cat_product_count": 13
        }
    ]
}
```

[demo site](https://onursultansu.com/test/)

[image]

Comment: I can see the categories you have made here but I don't understand how would you like to see the subcategories. and what items you would like to see inside? how do you know what item goes under what subcategory? perhaps you can show a more elaborated data set and better explanation of expected result

Comment: If I choose one of the categories that appear on the screen, it will appear on the screen in sequence, just like them. Whichever category I choose, its subcategories appear on the screen and i want to do these with json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON

```
{
  "cat_tr": [
    {
      "cat_name": "Product 1",
      "cat_url": "#",
      "cat_img": "img/product.png",
      "cat_product_count": 29,
      "cat_name_alt": [
        {
          "cat_name": "Product 1.1",
          "cat_url": "#",
          "cat_img": "img/product.png",
          "cat_product_count": 1
        },
        {
          "cat_name": "Product 1.2",
          "cat_url": "#",
          "cat_img": "img/product.png",
          "cat_product_count": 22
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "cat_name": "Product 2",
      "cat_url": "#",
      "cat_img": "img/product.png",
      "cat_product_count": 75
    },
    {
      "cat_name": "Product 3",
      "cat_url": "#",
      "cat_img": "img/product.png",
      "cat_product_count": 271,
      "cat_name_alt": [
        {
          "cat_name": "Product 3.1",
          "cat_url": "#",
          "cat_img": "img/product.png",
          "cat_product_count": 30
        },
        {
          "cat_name": "Product 3.2",
          "cat_url": "#",
          "cat_img": "img/product.png",
          "cat_product_count": 40
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "cat_name": "Product 4",
      "cat_url": "#",
      "cat_img": "img/product.png",
      "cat_product_count": 71
    }
  ]
}
```

JS

```
        $(function () {

            var categories = [];
            $.getJSON("category.json", function (data) {
                categories = data.cat_tr;
                $.each(categories, function (i, f) {
                    var cat_index = -1;
                    if (typeof f.cat_name_alt !== 'undefined' && f.cat_name_alt.length > 0) {
                        cat_index = i;
                    }
                    var tblRow = '<li class="grid_item" data-index="' + cat_index + '">' + '<a href="' + f.cat_url + '">' + '<div class="ic_grid">' + '<div class="cat_img">' + '<img src="' + f.cat_img + '">' + '</img>' + '</div>' + '<div class="cat_dec">' + f.cat_name + '<span>' + f.cat_product_count + '</span>' + '</div>' + '</div>' + '</a>' + '</li>'

                    $(tblRow).appendTo("#cat_list")
                });
            });

            $(document).on('click', '.grid_item', function (e) {
                if ($(this).data('index') != -1) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $('#cat_list').html('');
                    var sub_categories = categories[parseInt($(this).data('index'))].cat_name_alt;
                    $.each(sub_categories, function (i, f) {
                        var cat_index = -1;
                        if (typeof f.cat_name_alt !== 'undefined' && f.cat_name_alt.length > 0) {
                            cat_index = i;
                        }
                        var tblRow = '<li class="grid_item" data-index="' + cat_index + '">' + '<a href="' + f.cat_url + '">' + '<div class="ic_grid">' + '<div class="cat_img">' + '<img src="' + f.cat_img + '">' + '</img>' + '</div>' + '<div class="cat_dec">' + f.cat_name + '<span>' + f.cat_product_count + '</span>' + '</div>' + '</div>' + '</a>' + '</li>'

                        $(tblRow).appendTo("#cat_list")
                    });
                }
            });
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

If we assume subcategories stored in each object,

```json
{
    "cat_name": "Aluminum Components",
    "cat_url": "#",
    "cat_product_count": 29,
    "subcats": [
        {
          "cat_name": "First Subcategory",
          "cat_url": "#"
        },
        {
          "cat_name": "Second Subcategory",
          "cat_url": "#"
        }
    ]
}
```

You may try to implement that function to your code (I don't know JQuery so I wrote in vanilla JS);

```js
(categoryObject) => {
    if (categoryObject.subcats.length > 0) {
        var result = ""
        categoryObject.subcats.forEach(
            (subCategoryObject) => {
                var template = `<li class="subcategory"><a href="${subCategoryObject.cat_url}">${subCategoryObject.cat_name}</a></li>\n`
                result += template
            }
            return result
        )
    }
}
```